# MobileVLC Compile libcompat.a(dummy.o) has no symbols

Tags: ios5, vlc, libvlc

```
[info] Installing libvlc
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/libcompat.a(dummy.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/libcompat.a(tdestroy.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/libvlccore.a(cache.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/libvlccore.a(update_crypto.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/libvlccore.a(media_library.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/control/libmotion_plugin.a(libmotion_plugin_la-unimotion.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/video_filter/librotate_plugin.a(librotate_plugin_la-unimotion.o) has no symbols
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/liba52_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/liba52_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_attachment_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_attachment_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_avio_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_avio_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_ftp_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_ftp_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_http_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_http_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_mms_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_mms_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_rar_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_rar_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_tcp_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_tcp_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_udp_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_udp_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_vdr_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaccess_vdr_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libadpcm_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libadpcm_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaes3_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaes3_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libafile_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libafile_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaiff_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaiff_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libamem_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libamem_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaraw_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaraw_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libasf_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libasf_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libau_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libau_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaudio_endian_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaudio_endian_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaudio_format_neon_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaudio_format_neon_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaudio_format_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaudio_format_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaudioqueue_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libaudioqueue_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libavcodec_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libavcodec_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libavformat_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libavformat_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libavi_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libavi_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libblend_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libblend_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libcanvas_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libcanvas_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libcc_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libcc_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libcdg_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libcdg_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libchain_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libchain_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libchorus_flanger_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libchorus_flanger_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libcompressor_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libcompressor_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libcroppadd_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libcroppadd_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libcvdsub_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libcvdsub_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdash_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdash_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdecomp_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdecomp_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdeinterlace_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdeinterlace_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdemux_cdg_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdemux_cdg_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdemux_stl_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdemux_stl_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdemuxdump_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdemuxdump_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdirac_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdirac_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdolby_surround_decoder_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdolby_surround_decoder_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdts_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdts_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdvbsub_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libdvbsub_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libequalizer_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libequalizer_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libes_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libes_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libfilesystem_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libfilesystem_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libflac_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libflac_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libflacsys_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libflacsys_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libfloat32_mixer_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libfloat32_mixer_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libfolder_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libfolder_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libgain_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libgain_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libh264_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libh264_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libi420_rgb_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libi420_rgb_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libi420_yuy2_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libi420_yuy2_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libi422_i420_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libi422_i420_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libi422_yuy2_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libi422_yuy2_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libimage_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libimage_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libinteger_mixer_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libinteger_mixer_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libkaraoke_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libkaraoke_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/liblive555_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/liblive555_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/liblogo_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/liblogo_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/liblpcm_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/liblpcm_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmjpeg_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmjpeg_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmkv_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmkv_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmod_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmod_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmono_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmono_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmp4_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmp4_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmpeg_audio_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmpeg_audio_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmpgatofixed32_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmpgatofixed32_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmpgv_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libmpgv_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libnormvol_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libnormvol_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libnsc_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libnsc_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libnsv_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libnsv_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libnuv_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libnuv_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libogg_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libogg_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libopus_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libopus_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_dirac_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_dirac_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_flac_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_flac_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_h264_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_h264_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_mlp_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_mlp_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_mpeg4audio_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_mpeg4audio_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_mpeg4video_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_mpeg4video_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_mpegvideo_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_mpegvideo_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_vc1_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpacketizer_vc1_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libparam_eq_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libparam_eq_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libplaylist_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libplaylist_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpng_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpng_plugin.a are identical (not copied).
cp: /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpostproc_plugin.a and /Users/Eric/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/install-ios-OS/lib/vlc/plugins/libpostproc_plugin.a are identical (not copied).

[info] Removing unneeded modules
~/Documents/Develop/Project/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/package/ios
[info] Building MobileVLCKit (Aggregate static plugins)
[info] Building MobileVLCKit (MobileVLCKit)
[info] Building MobileMediaLibraryKit (MobileMediaLibraryKit)
[info] Building MobileVLC (MobileVLC)
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?
I get the source code from Git, and my develop environment is Xcode4.4.1 with Mac OS 10.8. And I tried Xcode4.2.1 with Mac OS 10.7,
I have been suffered this issue for a few days, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I also got the error, 'has no symbols' when I compiled the code in terminal. After (clean) deleting the previously built library/executable, though the message came again (has no symbols), my app got compiled in terminal.

I think, you can try cleaning the compilation and try again.